# Remove one of the added lines on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to only remove the line of the specific .delete that I press. How can I specify that in jQuery. Now it's removing all the p since I've chosen that as the value but I can't figure out how to make it specific for each line of append.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <h3>Shopping list</h3>
    <div class="line">
        <p class="title">Amount</p>
        <p class="title">Product</p>
        <p class="title">Price</p>
        <div>
            <input class='amountInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000' step='1'>
            <input class='productInput' type="text" name="message" value="">
            <input class='priceInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000000' step='0.01'>
            <button class="food">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div class="messages">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="totalPrice">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var totalPrice = 0;

$('.food').click(function() {
    var $frm = $(this).parent();
    var toAdd = $frm.children(".productInput").val();
    var addPrice = $frm.children(".priceInput").val();
    var addAmount = $frm.children(".amountInput").val();


    var div = $("<div>");
    div.append("<p>" + addAmount + "</p>", "<p id='product'> " + toAdd + " </p>", "<p>" + addPrice + "</p>", "<p class='delete'>" + "X" + "</p>");

    $frm.parent().children(".messages").append(div);

    totalPrice += addAmount * addPrice;

    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

});


});




 $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $('p').remove()


 });
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: When I click .food I add addAmount, toAdd and an X. When I click the p class="delete" I want it to remove the addAmount and toAdd that was added together with that specific letter X

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the parent div of the all the `p`, like:

```
// This is delegated event as the HTML element is added dynamically 
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove(); // .closest will traverse upwards to find the matched element that is div
});
```

**Note**: You need to use event delegation as the HTML elements are added dynamically. Learn more about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the elements that are being added, you'll just need to use `$(this)` within your function to refer to the element that triggered the call :

```
// When an element with the delete class is clicked
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    // Remove the closest <div> above the element that was clicked
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

**If you want to update pricing...**

When you remove your elements, you may want up consider updating your pricing as well, which you can do by reading your last element and subtracting it :

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    // Get the previous element which contains your price
    var priceToSubtract = parseInt($(this).prev().text());
    // Subtract the price
    totalPrice -= priceToSubtract;
    // Update your price
    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

This will require you to scope your `totalPrice` variable outside of your `$(document).ready()` block as seen below :

```
<script>
    var totalPrice = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
         // Your code here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: that will only remove the one I'm clicking on though, I want it to remove the 2 other <p> that was added together with the X.

Comment: in click event use :  ``$(this).closest("div").remove();`` this will remove all p tags

Comment: I just noticed this issue when going over the question again. I've updated accordingly. Additionally, you may want to consider updating your pricing upon removal of an element.