# Remove number from input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In connection to this question 
[Remove one of the added lines on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060725/remove-one-of-the-added-lines-on-click?noredirect=1#comment61668737_37060725)

I now want the total price to be updated when I remove the line. I realise that I need to use something similar to what I've used when I add a number to the total price but I don't know how to do this.

In short, when I add a line I want the price to be added on to the total price. When I am removing it I want the number that was on the removed line subtracted from the total price.I would need some help in how to access the addPrice and addAmount from a specific line.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <h3>Shopping list</h3>
    <div class="line">
        <p class="title">Amount</p>
        <p class="title">Product</p>
        <p class="title">Price</p>
        <div>
            <input class='amountInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000' step='1'>
            <input class='productInput' type="text" name="message" value="">
            <input class='priceInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000000' step='0.01'>
            <button class="food">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div class="messages">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="totalPrice">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalPrice = 0;
  $('.food').click(function() {
    var $frm = $(this).parent();
    var toAdd = $frm.children(".productInput").val();
    var addPrice = $frm.children(".priceInput").val();
    var addAmount = $frm.children(".amountInput").val();
    var div = $("<div>");
    div.append("<p>" + addAmount + "</p>", "<p id='product'> " + toAdd + " </p>", "<p>" + addPrice + "</p>", "<p class='delete'>" + "X" + "</p>");
    $frm.parent().children(".messages").append(div);
    totalPrice += addAmount * addPrice;
    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) My mistake

Comment: I didn't fully read the other thread, but it looks like the values you need are in the p elements next to it, correct? Do you have a working sample somewhere?

Comment: yeah, that's what I need. http://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/jqdydv

Comment: well it's already answered I guess ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the price and amount from the row you're deleting, and then subtract it from the total.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalPrice = 0;

  $('.food').click(function() {
    var $frm = $(this).parent();
    var toAdd = $frm.children(".productInput").val();
    var addPrice = $frm.children(".priceInput").val();
    var addAmount = $frm.children(".amountInput").val();

    var div = $("<div>");
    div.append("<p class='amount'>" + addAmount + "</p>", "<p class='product'> " + toAdd + " </p>", "<p class='price'>" + addPrice + "</p>", "<p class='delete'>" + "X" + "</p>");

    $frm.parent().children(".messages").append(div);

    totalPrice += addAmount * addPrice;

    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
    var subAmount = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".amount").text());
    var subPrice = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".price").text());
    totalPrice -= subAmount * subPrice;
    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

    $(this).closest("div").remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <h3>Shopping list</h3>
  <div class="line">
    <p class="title">Amount</p>
    <p class="title">Product</p>
    <p class="title">Price</p>
    <div>
      <input class='amountInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000' step='1'>
      <input class='productInput' type="text" name="message" value="">
      <input class='priceInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000000' step='0.01'>
      <button class="food">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="messages">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="totalPrice">
</div>
```

I've also assigned classes to the amount and price elements so I don't have to hard-code their positions in the DIV.

BTW, you shouldn't use `id='product'` in the row, because you're creating multiple elements with the same ID. IDs are supposed to be unique. I've changed it to a class.

Comment: I've added a demo, it works. I forgot to update the `totalPrice` DIV before, is that what the problem was?

Comment: "you shouldn't use id='product'" agreed, and perhaps fix it in your answer?

Comment: Thanks. I wrote that before I copied his code into my answer, and forgot about it.

Comment: yeah, thanks that was the issue. I suspected that might have been it but since I'm quite new to this I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

What about storing the price for each added div in its data object?

```
var div = $("<div>");
div.data("price", addAmount * addPrice);
```

Then access it again in the delete event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var div = $(this).closest("div");
    totalPrice -= div.data("price");
    div.remove();
}
```